# UITableView row won't removed after being deleted

Tags: swift, tableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm having the problem where after i had deleted my `tableview` row, the row won't removed, here is the code, i had follow the tutorial online, and it successfully delete from data model, but it won't dismiss the deleted row unless I unwind back to previous screen and back to this view, why is it? :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {

        let product = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Product

        let productName = product.name

        let message = (MCLocalization.sharedInstance.stringForKey("cart_remove_one_item_message",  replacements: ["%s" : productName!]))
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: (MCLocalization.sharedInstance.stringForKey("cart_remove_title")), message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {
            (_)in

            let managedObject : NSManagedObject = self.frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NSManagedObject
            self.moc.deleteObject(managedObject)
            self.tableView.reloadData()

            do {
                try self.moc.save()  
            } catch {
                print("Failed to save.")
                return
            }
        })

        alert.addAction(OKAction)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove object from your array also then reload your `tableView` after `moc.save()` successfully.

```
let managedObject : NSManagedObject = self.frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NSManagedObject
self.moc.deleteObject(managedObject)
do {
   try self.moc.save()

} catch {
    print("Failed to save.")
    return
}
```

**Edit:**
You need to add that in your question that you are using `NSFetchedResultsController`, Now i think you have set the delegate with your `self.frc.delegate = self`, then add this delegate method also remove the `reloadData` there is no need for that now.

```
func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    tableView.endUpdates()
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
    switch type {
    case .Insert:
        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    case .Delete:
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    default: break
    }
}
```

Fore more detail about NSFetchedResultsController check tutorials it will help you.

- [Using NSFetchedResultsController to Display Data with Swift](http://www.learncoredata.com/nsfetchedresultscontroller-swift/)
- [Core Data and Swift: NSFetchedResultsController](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-and-swift-nsfetchedresultscontroller--cms-25072)

Comment: it has a error "value of type 'NSFetchResultsController' has no member 'remove object'."

Answer (score 2):

You're reloading the table before you save the deletions, so you're getting a reloaded table that still contains that same data. Put `self.tableView.reloadData()` after the save.